# Meaning of look up to God and its usage

Tags: american-english, spoken-english

When we say we're seeking for help from God. We look up to him. Is this correct ?

Comment: [to seek help from someone]

Answer (score 12):

The word to be careful of here is "up".  **To look up to X** is an idiom meaning "to have respect or admiration for X," and implies that X is seen as something of a role model.

Omitting the word "up", **to look to X** is an idiom with the meaning you want.  It means to rely on X for help.  Usually with this phrase you would also add what you are hoping for.  For example, "I looked to my parents for support", or "He looked to his friends for help."

Comment: Agreed, this is an interesting question to illustrate the subtle distinction between "look to" and "look up to".

Comment: So what do I say here to imply seeking God's help?

Comment: @ArdisEll You can say, "We look to God for help."

Comment: @ArdisEll Or you can leave "help" implicit. e.g. _"When the church has financial problems, we look to God."_ What you're looking to God for is implied by the context (if you have problems, you typically look for help or solutions), so the "for help" can be [ellipsed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics)).

Comment: I think I would add that, although this is a very good and correct answer, you will likely be understood either way, given the right context.  If someone said to me, "I trust in God. When life gets tough, I look up to him", I wouldn't be confused.  I think this is because in the context of God/religion, "up" is often used to mean "toward Heaven" and it would probably be understood this way due to the context.  Still, it is much better to say "look to him" instead.

Comment: This question is **not** concerned with the use of a preposition. What if, instead of "God", the object of _from_ were "the dogcatcher?" This is a question on theology, not English, I think.

Comment: to look up to someone, it can be anyone. One would not look "up" to God. Though one might Look to God for help. As opposed to looking to drugs for help.